# Find and click with capybara inconsistent in headless/normal mode after upgrade

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I upgraded my driver and gems for Capybara for a fully-tested app.

Afterwards I noticed that some feature specs were failing it seems because the element isn't on the screen (it's visible, but out of scroll) at the time when `click` is called?

So this now fails half the time in non-headless mode. Is this because it's it's not on the screen and must be scrolled to?

```rb
  find("#am_departure_review button").click
```

But if I do this it works:

Is this a new configuration? A discrepancy between the drivers (I went from `chromedriver-helper` to `webdrivers`)? Something else I'm missing?

I suppose it might also be a window height discrepancy involving the window height in normal mode. The height I'm trying to give the window doesn't seem to take in non-headless mode:

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :my_selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
    opts.args << '--headless'
    opts.args << '--window-size=1380,5000'
    opts.args << '--disable-notifications'
    opts.args << '--disable-gpu' if Gem.win_platform?
    opts.args << '--disable-site-isolation-trials'
  end
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
    opts.args << '--window-size=1380,5000'
    opts.args << '--disable-notifications'
    opts.args << '--disable-gpu' if Gem.win_platform?
    opts.args << '--disable-site-isolation-trials'
  end
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end



Capybara.server_port      = 57124
Capybara.save_path        = capybara_save_path
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5 #default is 2
Capybara.raise_server_errors = false

if ENV['CAPYBARA_DRIVER'] == 'headless' # CAPYBARA_DRIVER=headless rspec
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :my_selenium_chrome_headless
  Capybara.current_driver    = :my_selenium_chrome_headless
  Capybara.default_driver    = :my_selenium_chrome_headless
else
  Capybara.javascript_driver     = :selenium_chrome
  Capybara.current_driver        = :selenium_chrome
  Capybara.default_driver        = :selenium_chrome
end
```

Comment: What version of Capybara did you upgrade from -> to ? What other gems did you update.  Technically swapping from chromedriver-helper to webdrivers shouldn't make a difference since all they do is install the correct version of chromedriver - the actual Capybara driver remains the same. When you say "fails" do you get an error (if so what error exactly) or just silently doesn't click what you think it should? Also do you have any other global Capybara settings changed? For instance you haven't set Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements to false?

Comment: Oh - and you can't set the window size larger than the screen - does your screen have 5000 px vertical resolution?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole It just doesn't click the element. It moves it into view, and then the click never happens. I don't have ignore_hidden_elements set anywhere, and no my screen doesn't have 5000px, I was just trying to make it big to avoid this issue. But I was wrong, it only works sometimes doing the straight find first.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what JS driven behaviors are attached to the element it's tough to say exactly what's happening but I'd try something like `button = page.find("#am_departure_review button"); page.scroll_to(button); button.click` - and possibly putting a short sleep before `button.click` just to work out exactly what makes it work 100%. From that one can then narrow down the possible causes and solutions.